# Problem while installing a React Native App on physical phone

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

When I run "yarn android", to install the app on the phone I get this error:

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Unable to install /home/dapedo/Projects/CJR/test/AwesomeProject/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I already checked the system PATH and all seems to be correct:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:~/android-studio/bin
```

I tried to run it on Android Studio, and it install the app, but I get some error, probably because there's no connection. When I run "yarn android" with the app open, I get a blank page instead of the errors, but the same error appears on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command

`chmod 755 android/gradlew`

inside your app root folder
then run

`react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

I went to the Android SDK cofigs, and disabled all the unused things, than initialized a new React Native project, that solved my problem.